# Can Google Analytics cause site stability problems under Windows 2000?

Tags: google, analytics, iis, windows

Recently we added the code for Google Analytics to our web site.  This code was added to a header.asp root include file that is used in all pages of our entire site.  Since this was added we began to see different behaviors of our site and in some instances one of the servers was found to not serve web pages for nearly 12 hours (we have a load balanced farm obviously).

Are there any issues with the GA piece in an older Windows 2000 IIS environment?  Would the placement of the JavaScript code in the header root include file contribute to this issue?

Comment: Just to clarify: was the site not served at all, or just not the updated version?

Answer (score 1):

It seems very unlikely that Google Analytics is causing your site stability problems.

The code for Google Analytics runs client side (not server side) so it shouldn't be putting any additional strain on your servers.  In fact, the Google Analytics JavaScript doesn't even call back to your servers for additional resources, it reports usage statistics to Google's servers.

The only resources used by your servers should be the extra memory and parsing required to serve a couple lines of static JavaScript.  I've never seen a server setup where that was enough to push a server over the edge and cause errors.  In all likelihood, your stability problems are caused by something else.